# Doubt about the proof of Montel's theorem

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I'm taking a complex analysis course and I am stuck at the very beginning of the proof of Mantel's theorem (the rest of the proof is ok). The doubt, however, is of topological nature. The setting is the following:
we were given the definition of the compact-open topology on $C^0(X, Y)$, the statement of Ascoli-Arzelà theorem, and the professor left to us as an exercise to proof that if $Y=\mathbb{R^n}$, then convergence in this topology is equivalent to uniform convergence on compacts. Until here, everything's fine. Then, he stated the theorem, in this form:
a uniformly bounded family of holomorphic functions defined on an open set is relatively compact in the space of all holomorphic functions defined on that open set. He started the proof saying that it is sufficient to prove that every sequence in this family has a convergent subsequence. In some books, this is the actual statement of the theorem, but I also found some source where it is stated as our professor did (Wikipedia, for example). My doubt is: why are these two formulation equivalent? I know it is true in metric spaces, but it is not obvious that the compact-open topology is metrizable, at least not for me, unless I'm missing some very trivial facts.

Comment: The compact open topology is metrizable. You basically take the sup norm on each set of an increasing sequence of compact sets and sum them all up. See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541086/how-do-i-prove-that-the-compact-open-topology-is-metrizable.

Comment: Oh, it was so simple... Thanks a lot!